# Azure HTTP Trigger function using Azurite local storage emulator

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azurite

Starting a new Azure HTTP Function project using Visual Studio Community 2022.

According to the official docs, [the Azure Storage Emulator is depreciated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) and [Azurite is automatically available with Visual Studio 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio).

Using the command line,

```
> azurite.exe --help
```

indicates files are stored "by default, in the current process working directory." One can start azurite.exe manually [via the command line with a --location switch](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite#workspace-path-configuration), but is there any way to **specify the location via a configuration file or option somewhere in Visual Studio when the project is run** without manually starting azurite with a specific location?

For example, if I want to use the following path instead:

```
E:\temp\azurite\
```

The other strange thing is, when in Visual Studio project explorer, under "Connected Services" and you right-click on the "Storage Azurite emulator", as shown below:

[image]

the following options show up --

[image]

To launch the depreciated "Azure Storage Emulator" -- That does not make sense (to me).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this [GitHub Doc of Azurite](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite#workspace-path-configuration) where the workspace path of Azurite Emulator is given as optional and can specify our own path!

Comment: Yes - have you read my original post? -- The question was:  specify the location via a configuration file or option somewhere in Visual Studio when the project is run